# Types of inheritance is supported in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i guess only these two types are available in swift, i just want to know, am i missing any, your help will be appreciated?

- **Single**
- **Multilevel**

Comment: What is "multi-level inheritance"? Meaning you can subclass a subclass? Is that restricted in some languages?

Comment: @virus : Yes you're correct, In iOS(Swift) Single and Multi-Level inheritance exists among the basic inheritances(Singe, Multi-level, Multiple). Multiple inheritance is not possible in Swift.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes in Swift and Objective-c **Single** and **Multilevel inheritance** is supported.

In swift and many other languages **Multiple Inheritance** is restricted by use of classes because of historical problems like *deadly diamond* and others ambiguities.In swift you can achieve the **Multiple inheritance** at some level by `Protocols`.

Comment: That's not inheritance that's protocol conformity. Conforming to a protocol means implementing or inheriting an implementation from super.

Comment: That's why I have used "at some level" in answer. I know it is not multiple inheritance at full fledge because you can not have state and deadly diamond but you can achieve polymorphism benefits at some level.

Comment: @uchuugaka why not polymorphism can be achieved by protocols. A good reference for basic concept is in this article https://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html There are many design patterns which used Protocols polymorphism to hide the details of implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Only those two are avaliable in swift but you can implement multiple inheritance.You could use a protocol to achieve the same result as Multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

iOS supported Inheritance types.

1. Single
2. Multilevel
3. Hierarchical
4. Hybrid (combination of more than one form of inheritance)

Note: Multiple Inheritance not supported by many modern languages, due to avoid Diamond shape ambiguity.

Yes, both languages (Swift and Objective-C) support hierarchical inheritance. There are countless examples in the iOS SDK.

UIResponder is subclassed by UIApplication, UIView, UIViewController.

UIView obviously has many subclasses as does UIViewController.

And Hybrid also, here is a sample, combination of Multilevel and Hierarchical.

```
class Parent {
    fun_f1
}

class Child1: Parent {
    fun_f2
}

class Child2: Parent {
    fun_f3
}

class Child3: Child1 {
    fun_f4
}

class TestHybrid { 
    fun test() { 
        var c3: Child3  
        c3.f1();  
        c3.f2();   
        c3.f4();    
    } 
}
```